# Enum valueOf some Object with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, enums, thymeleaf

I have an enum and I want to use valueOf(some object) in thymeleaf :

```
<p th:text="${T(com.dileoz.pov.utils.ApplicationStatus).valueOf('__${applicatie.status.rawValue}__')}"></p>
```

This result in:

[image]

while if I try to use a hardcoded enum value:

```
<p th:text="${T(com.dileoz.pov.utils.ApplicationStatus).valueOf('New')}"></p>
```

It works ..
So how do I use an object value in the Enum valueOf option in thymeleaf ?

Thx in adavance

Answer (score 0):

It was throwing the error because valueOf doesn't containt the element "NotDispatched" ..

So the code:

```
<p th:text="${T(com.dileoz.pov.utils.ApplicationStatus).valueOf('__${applicatie.status.rawValue}__')}"></p>
```

Works perfectly .. 
My bad - apologise